# What are these physicists talking about? Dyadic green function?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, tensor-products, tensors

I am interested in a mathematical explanation(in the sense that you say for example: is it a mapping from A to B) what a dyadic green function and the unit dyad actually is? I am reading this as though it is a matrix and the unit dyad is the identity, but somehow this whole thing confuses me. (Probably, because I do not know anything about tensors)

[Definition of Dyadic green function and unit dyad](http://www.photonics.ethz.ch/fileadmin/user_upload/optics/Courses/PhysicalOpticsII/notes4.pdf)

Comment: A dyadic Green's function is just a matrix-valued (or better, linear transformation-valued) Green's function. The use of dyads is an extraordinarily old-fashioned convention, dating from a time when linear algebra as we know it (i.e., matrices and linear transformations) was still considered unacceptably exotic and high tech, that still somehow survives in certain branches of engineering.

Comment: and this identity dyad is what? a unit matrix? maybe you post it as an answer, so that I can accept your answer ;-)...thank you very much

Comment: Actually, you'd might as well take a look at this question and both its answers: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/351207/49610 Certainly, though, the unit dyad is just the identity matrix.